# Run python script from another python script based on time and keyboard interruption

Tags: python, asynchronous

I created two python scripts: One with user inputs and other with infinite loop. I want to run the first script and if the user does not press any key within 2 seconds it goes to the second script automatically and when it enters second script the user can still interrupt it if a key is pressed.
This goes on and on like screensaver mechanism.

I was able to get the timeout part correct but it does not go back to the first script. Please help

Here are my two scripts:

**`Script 1:`**

```
 import subprocess
    from threading import Timer
    out_of_time=False
    def time_ran_out():
        subprocess.call("python s2.py 1", shell=True)
        out_of_time=True
    t=Timer(2,time_ran_out)
    t.start()
    while 1==1:
        x = input("Enter here: ")
        if x!=None and not out_of_time:
            print(x)
    t.cancel()
```

Script 2:

```
try:
    while True:
        print ("Hello World")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

So the output should be

```
Enter here:
```

if no key is pressed for 2 seconds it should start running second script:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

If a key is pressed it should go back to first script again.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried putting anything in the except block, other than pass? It seems like calling the other script from there would get the desired effect, but I can't test it right now. Also, when you want an infinite loop, you should generally do while true: rather than while 1==1:

Comment: This is probably more easily approached using `asyncio` rather than multiple subprocesses.